# Double turns into nan in C

Tags: c, floating-point, double, nan

I have a function that uses an `int`, say `2488`, to store temperature values. I have to call a function `getTemp()` to get the int. The `getTemp` function returns a `double` and uses the `int` to return the correct number. All the `getTemp()` does is `return (double)x / 100.0` where `x` is `2488` in this case.

The returned double is then `24.88`. This value then is sent to another function that adds the `double` to an array. Function is called `DAaddDouble(double m, int x, int y)` where `m` is the value to add, `x` and `y` is the coordinates that specify where to add the `double`.

Problem is, it turns into `nan`.

```
double a = getTemp();
//a is correct, i.e. 24.88
DAaddDouble(a, x, y);
/*-----------inside DAaddDouble----------*/
void DAaddDouble(double m, int x, int y)
{
   //at this point, a (or m, same) is 0.nan
   cord = x + y*40; //where to put the double
   snprintf(DARRAY[cord], 5, "%f",m);
   printf(....DARRAY[cord]...);

}
```

output: `-nan`

Comment: How you defined DARRAY? Change DAaddDouble function to void DAaddDouble(double m, int x, int y) as a or m is 24.88

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a typo, it is double but the problem still remains.

Comment: How you defined DARRAY?

Comment: Your problem is unlikely to be in the fragment you quoted. Try stepping through the lines in a debugger to see when exactly `m` becomes `NaN`, if ever.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of function `DAaddDouble` is:

```
void DAaddDouble(int m, int x, int y)
```

Note that `m` is of type `int`, and inside the function, you have:

```
snprintf(DARRAY[cord], 5, "%f",m);
```

in which `%f` expects type `double`, it's undefined behavior.

Probably what you need is to have the parameter `m` as `double`(as in your words above the code).

```
void DAaddDouble(double m, int x, int y)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a typo, it is double but the problem still remains.

Answer (score 0):

Mis-match prototype.

Usage of `DAaddDouble()` is not preceded by its declaration/definition, thus the compiler assumes the function is:

```
int DAaddDouble(int m, int x, int y);
```

Precede the usage of `DAaddDouble()` by the function definition or a function prototype.

```
void DAaddDouble(double m, int x, int y);
```

A good compiler will warn of this.  Insure all warning are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know `m` is `NAN`. If you have infered by the value "printed" to `DARRAY[cord]`, take into account that the format string should be `"%lf"` and not `"%f"`.

```
void DAaddDouble(double m, int x, int y)
{
   //at this point, a (or m, same) is 0.nan
   cord = x + y*40; //where to put the double
   snprintf(DARRAY[cord], 5, "%f",m); /* should be "%lf" for printing doubles */
   printf(....DARRAY[cord]...);

}
```

Comment: _format string should be `"%lf"` and not `"%f"`_ is not correct.  Either will work.  It makes a functional difference with `scanf()`, but not `printf()`  "l (ell) ... has no effect on a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion" C11dr §7.21.6.1 7.  `m` as a `float` or `double` is converted/passed to `snprintf()` as a `double`.
specifier.